# Display MongoDB data in ChartJS with time interval using AngularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs, mongodb, chart.js

I have a MongoDB that stores humidity with timestamps. This is what my collection looks like :

```
[{ "_id" : ObjectId("585db63541472bf7683eb3c5"), "datetime" : ISODate("2016-12-23T23:41:41.897Z"), "temperature" : 19, "humidity" : 23 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("585db63a41472bf7683eb3c6"), "datetime" : ISODate("2016-12-23T23:41:46.927Z"), "temperature" : 19, "humidity" : 23 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("585db63f41472bf7683eb3c7"), "datetime" : ISODate("2016-12-23T23:41:51.956Z"), "temperature" : 19, "humidity" : 23 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("585db644483ab4f778a635bf"), "datetime" : ISODate("2016-12-23T23:41:56.991Z"), "temperature" : 19, "humidity" : 23 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("585db64a483ab4f778a635c0"), "datetime" : ISODate("2016-12-23T23:42:02.032Z"), "temperature" : 19, "humidity" : 23 }]
```

I have successfully use this JSON data to plot a dynamic chart with ChartJS.

**chart.js** code

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/api/humidity",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            var labeldata = [];
            var chartData = [];
            for(var i =0; i < result.length; i++)
            {
                labeldata.push(result[i].when);
                chartData.push(result[i].message)
            }


            var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
            var myChart = new Chart (ctx, {
                type : "line",
                data: {
                    labels: labeldata,
                    datasets: [
                        {
                            label: "Humidity",
                            fill: false,
                            lineTension: 0.1,
                            backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)",
                            borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                            borderCapStyle: 'butt',
                            borderDash: [],
                            borderDashOffset: 0.0,
                            borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
                            pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                            pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
                            pointBorderWidth: 1,
                            pointHoverRadius: 5,
                            pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                            pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                            pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
                            pointRadius: 1,
                            pointHitRadius: 10,
                            data: chartData
                        },

                    ]
                }
            });
        }
    })
});
```

However I would like to bind a dropdown menu with time intervals to my chart. I'm a little confused on where I should implement this. I should mention that i'm collecting my data every minute. Can I achieve this with ChartJS ?

I will appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: You havn't posted what you have tried.

Comment: I'm currently sourcing for information so far I haven't found anything relating. I'm a newbie to JS.

Comment: The purpose of Stack Overflow is to help people solve programming problems. The concept is that you have a go at solving a problem, and the community will help you. There is information about questions here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Mikkel Thanks for the tips. I was looking for ideas or some guidance as to how I can achieve my goal. Im currently working on the above mentioned topic and would post some progress later on.

Comment: I understand what you want, but you haven't been specific about what you are looking for, and have no example code. Edit the question to include code (even if it's wrong/not working) and people will help

Comment: @Mikkel Thanks for reaching out. I have pasted an update of my code and also what i'm looking to achieve eventually.